# Redirecting input separated with spaces

Tags: bash, shell

Hi I've a question about feeding inputs to this simple bash script I wrote. All it does is add a set of flags to my compile operation to save me having to write them in myself every time. I can run it by using `echo myprogram.c -o myprogram -llibrary | ./Compile`.
But I can't find a way to run it in the way I expected to be able to, `./Compile < myprogram.c -o myprogram -llibrary`
I've tried a few combinations of quotes and brackets to no avail, can anyone tell me how to feed the same input as produced by echo using the redirect input command.

```
#!/bin/bash
# File name Compile
#Shortcut to compile with all the required flags, name defaulting to
#first input ending in .c
echo "Enter inputs: "
read inputs
gcc -Wall -W -pedantic -std=c89 -g -O $inputs
exit 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your shell to:

```
#!/bin/bash
gcc -Wall -W -pedantic -std=c89 -g -O "$@"
```

Then you can only write(no redirection needed):

```
./Compile myprogram.c -o myprogram -llibrary
```

BTW, don't explicitly write `exit 0` at end of this shell. It is redundant when `gcc` succeeds, and is wrong when gcc fails(exit code 1 will be overwritten).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [process substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution%5d):

```
./Compile < <( echo myprogram.c -o myprogram -llibrary )
```

the above line produces the same result as your original command:

```
echo myprogram.c -o myprogram -llibrary | ./Compile
```